# sort keys across multiple dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list that contains multiple small dictionaries, something like this:

```
_history = [{ "field" : "field01", "mode" : "write"},
            { "field" : "field02", "mode" : "write"},
            { "field" : "field03", "mode" : "write"},
            { "field" : "field01", "mode" : "clear"}]
```

What I'm interested in is the best way to process the list of dictionaries and determine if the same field value shows up more than once (in this case 'field01') and if it does, I'd like to verify whether the mode is the same.  In the example above, I have a conflict on field01 and I'd like to raise an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def validate(hist)
    key = itemgetter('field')
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(hist, key=key), key=key):
        s = set(d['mode'] for d in g)
        if len(s) > 1:
            raise ValueError(k)

>>> validate(_history)
Traceback ...
ValueError: field01
```

Comment: thanks schwobaseggl, that worked exactly as I was hoping